# is it possible to run process that use only 2 CPU from 16 CPU in my linux machine

Tags: linux, rhel, process, cpu

is it possible to run process that use only 2 CPU from 16 CPU in my linux machine

we have red-hat machine version 6
and we have 16 CPU

but because license cost money and if we limit the script that will run only on 2 CPU then we can save the money

Comment: It's technically possible, I'm not sure it would help with your license though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict a process to running on a specific (set of) cores with [`taskset`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset).

```
taskset 3 mycommand
```

(`3` is a bit mask, meaning that `mycommand` will only run on cores 0 and 1.)

However, this won't change how many CPUs the process thinks you have. It's only an instruction to the kernel not to schedule the process on CPUs other than the ones listed in the bit mask. So if the program does a license check based on the number of CPUs, this probably won't help.

A solution that would definitely work is to run the process in a virtual machine with only 2 (virtual) cores. However this might cost performance.

[Cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) offers an intermediate way of limiting the resources that a process may use. I don't know whether it can effectively hide CPUs from the process or whether it only acts like `taskset`.

Comment: Hi Gilles , what in case I do the following taskset 3 /var/tmp/task_stop , while task_stop script include inside more then 50 other tasks , so is it mean that all others tasks will be used also 2 CPU?

Comment: @yael `taskset` affects the command that you pass and all the processes that it starts.